# unable to add comments, close or delete

Tags: support, javascript

I am not able to add comments, close questions, delete comments. I am only able to perform editing. Is a Stack Overflow server problem, or is something wrong from my side?

Comment: You're [this SO user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/388341/subanki), right?

Comment: Are the buttons to do this hidden or does nothing happen when you click them? Also, I assume you're referring to StackOverflow and not meta.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Comment button not working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65476/add-comment-button-not-working)

Comment: @Tim Yes you are right

Comment: @Simon Brown Yes i am referring to SO. For some odd reason the buttons seem to work now. Don't know why it wasn't working then.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a JavaScript problem.

1. Clear your browser cache
2. Try in a different web browser

Comment: Ah yes I tried them yesterday, but didn't help much. But Today it seems to work correctly